# How to draw a line after every fourth word in ObjectListView C#

Tags: c#, objectlistview

this is how I add data to ObjectListView

```
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectListViewList.Count; i++)
{
for(int k=0; k<4;k++){
    AddObjectListView newObject = new AddObjectListView(ObjectListViewList[i][k]);
    objectListView1.AddObject(newObject);}
}
```

what do I need to add, so that after each filled 4 elements(after passing the loop with int k), a line of any color is drawn, as in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir1fP.png)

Comment: Maybe instead of a ListView, add objects to a panel and then draw the line on the panel.

Comment: Of course you will have to specify the x and y location of the objects you are adding.

Comment: Will the lines be filled in and displayed just as quickly?

Comment: I use panels to create custom checked listbox controls. The users cannot tell the difference. Just create a new class that extends panel. Then create methods like AddItem and Drawline. Keep track of the Y value of Position so you know where you are creating the controls Vertically on the panel.

Comment: Here is a good example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/creating-custom-controls-in-C-Sharp/